# SharePoint 2010 Claims

Tags: authentication, forms-authentication

I've got a SharePoint portal configured to use Claims based authentication. I'm able to login using this, but each time I click a link within the portal, I'm redirected to the logon page. Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the initial login, a session cookie is used to persist the identity. Sounds like you are blocking cookies.